How can I specify the home directory to be different than the location of the ssh keys?
Currently I have a client that wants to connect to a RHEL 8.8 server via sftp using ssh keys. Now, he wants the home page for that user to be a folder that looks like /interfaces/users/shar/, which is used by other users in the server, so I set his home folder to be that path I mentioned earlier but he can't connect to that server unless I move the ssh keys to that path, which is not secure since it's a shared path and we don't want others to see that .ssh directory in that directory so a desired scenario would be that his ssh keys stay in the /home/'user' directory but that when he connects to ftp he lands in /interfaces/users/shar/ directory.
What I have tried so far is that I created a soft link inside /home/'user' directory that points to /interfaces/users/shar/ so when he lands on his home directory he can cd into that softlink and then be transported to the desired directory but for security reasons he doesn't want any user to land in a directory where all the profile files and ssh files are even when they are hidden because the sftp software shows them to whoever is logging in.
Is there then a configuration I can try to place the ssh keys in a different place other than the home directory and that he can still be able to ssh to that server?

There's an AuthorizedKeysFile parameter in the OpenSSH sshd_config - see for example the related question ssh into an account which has no home directory

Also, bear in mind that the only key that has to be in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is the public key, which is of course, public.  So the security risk ought to be minimal. But yes, @steeldriver's  point is apt, as well as the sshd_config directive 'AuthorizedKeysCommand' which allows you to set up highly customizable authentication arrangements.

Thank you @steeldriver and Jim L. However, I believe that if I edit that file that configuration will change for all the users trying to ssh to the system not just my client, right?

@VaTo not so if you use a Match directive similar to that shown in this answer to the linked question. You would use Match user rather than Match group to limit to a specific client - for a full list of available match criteria see your system's man sshd_config.

See this answer for a detailed description of how the Match directives are parsed in the sshd_config file.  The conclusion is that the Match lines (and their following parameter lines) should be at the end of the file.  As soon as sshd sees the first Match line, it stops looking for global parameters.

The case can be made that if this is going to be useful for one user, it's
probably likely that another user will eventually request a similar setup.
Another way to put that is, for it to be okay for one user, it should okay
for any (trusted) user.  So consider solutions that, once deployed, are easy
to expand to additional users in the future.
Here's one example (out of many possible solutions), based on the bash
shell, of how to put the public key for user in a secure location in a
manner that is scalable to any number of users.  You will need to adjust the
reference to user to match the actual username, and also ensure that the path to the bash shell is correct for your system.
Also note that the key is placed in an area so secure that only the root user can alter it.  So if the
user creates a new public key, you'll have to install it for them.  That's not
difficult to do, but you should be aware of that.
Set some variables and create some directories:
# u='user'  #  <<--  set this
# umask 77
# mkdir /root/bin
# mkdir -p /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/"$u"

Create an "AuthorizedKeysCommand" script that sshd will use:
# cat << \EOF > /root/bin/authorized_keys.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Per config line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

# AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/local/bin/bash /root/bin/authorized_keys.sh %u %f %k

# param 1 is %u (username)

eval d="~$1"

[[ -d "$d/.ssh/authorized_keys.d" ]] &&
        cat "$d"/.ssh/authorized_keys.d/*.conf 2>/dev/null ||
        true

[[ -d "/etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/$1" ]] &&
        cat "/etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/$1"/*.conf 2>/dev/null ||
        true
EOF

Add a couple configuration lines to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/local/bin/bash /root/bin/authorized_keys.sh %u %f %k
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root

Now, add the user's public key to a file named *.conf in directory
/etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/"$u":
# cat /path/to/users-public-key.pub > \
      /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/"$u"/users-public-key.pub.conf

Double-check that permissions are tight:
# chmod -R u+rwX,go= /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d
# chmod -R u+rwx,go= /root/bin/

And finally, restart the sshd service:
# service sshd restart

In review, this approach creates optional per-user directories under /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d.  Each user's directory can contain any number of public keys so long as they are stored in a filename that watches the *.conf wildcard.  Once stored, any of those public keys will be accepted for login but only by that user.  Keys can contain restrictions and any other features that are supported in a normal authorized_keys file.
To add any other user to this scheme in the future, you need only create a secure /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/user directory, and copy their public key into a *.conf file in that directory:
# u='user'
# umask 77
# mkdir -p /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/"$u"
# cat /path/to/users-public-key.pub > /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/"$u"/users-public-key.pub.conf

No restart of sshd is necessary when simply adding or changing a user's public key.
